# Why does the .NetCore Class Library reference .NetStandard?

Tags: .net-core-rc1

In VS2015 > New Project > .Net Core, there is a template for "Class Library (.NET Core)"

It wasn't until I tried to reference this library in a .NET Core Web API program, that I realized that the Class Library template is referencing .NETStandard v1.6. And my .NET Core API porject won't take it as a reference. I was trying to avoid building the library as a nuget package.

Any ideas on why a Core template isn't referencing core?
Any ideas on quick workarounds?

Update: 
Opened a new "Class Library (.NET Core)", before first build I changed frameworks in project.json to

`"netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]`

Then I created, in a different VS instance, a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)".

I tried to add a reference to the .dll file for the new class library, now in a netcoreapp1.0 folder and I still get the same error:

> .NET Core Projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release.

Comment: Forget everything about that and start from scratch in Visual Studio 2017. Don't waste your precious time.

Comment: @LexLi It's still good to know what's happening under the hood though :)

Comment: @goaty Yes, especially if you are intending to write a library that is aim to be used by different framework as I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to fix your problem**

> I was trying to avoid building the library as a nuget package.
>
> Any ideas on why a Core template isn't referencing core? Any ideas on quick workarounds?

When you try to add the .dll as a reference for the API, your error message should say somewhere that you need to create a package in order to use that class library. It is described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/getting-started/consuming-library-with-visual-studio-2017).

However if you do not want to bother to make a package, for example if your class library is used now only in your API project, the easiest way is to build your class library as a Project of your Solution where the API lives. To do so, copy-paste your code in the Solution folder and include it as a project.

**Some explanations about the version and frameworks**

The Core template (I guess you are talking about the .NET Core API) should create a project.json with

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
         "imports": [
             "dotnet5.6",
             "portable-net45+win8"
       ]
    }
  }
```

Let's see what the lines are responsible for:

- `netcoreapp1.0` under `frameworks` means your API is targeting the framework .NET Core 1.0. That version of the .NET Core framework implements the .NET Standard 1.6 ([the list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)) Good thing: your Class library also use this .NET Standard 1.6. Knowing the .NET Standard 1.6 that your Class library is using make you able to choose what version of .NET Core/Xamarin/.NET Framework you can use when you later want to develop a Web app/Mobile app/Windows software for example
- `imports` lists other frameworks/version of packages that your application can use
- According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks) `dotnet5.6` and `portable-net45+win8` are deprecated and a `netstandard` version should be used instead. `dotnet5.6` is still mysterious for me. `portable-net45+win8` is equivalent to `netstandard1.0`. If you let it it means that your application can use package using .NET Standard 1.0. This can be a problem because .NET Core 1.0 starts with .NET Standard 1.6 so I would actually delete those two lines.

That being said, I am more than welcome for comments!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like other answers (before this) didn't get to the point.
`.NET Standard` is the way forward to write .NET class libraries because it follows a set of standard APIs that can run on virtually all .NET runtimes (full framework, .NET core, Mono Xamarin...)

So if you want to write a `.NET core` library, you're effectively writing a `.NET Standard` library. No need to differentiate them. The reference to `.NET standard 1.6` is to let the compiler know what to compile against.
`netcoreapp1.0` is basically for `.NET core` console apps. A `netcoreapp1.0` project will compile to dll that can be executed (contains program entry like `static void Main()`)

So it makes sense why you can't have that in a library :)

Comment: Read again my answer. I did not say the contrary. I am giving a full explanation of Web API **using** a library for .NET Standard ;-)
However `netcoreapp1.0` is not only for .NET Core console apps. That framework enables you to run MVC on the top.

Comment: I still don't understand then, if my Class Library is a .NETStandard 1.6 why can't I load it as a reference to a .NETCoreApp?

Comment: @Steve'Kepano'Eggering Your API can use your class library. You have 2 ways to do it. First way: make your class library a package and reference it. Second way: if don't want to make a package, then your only solution is to "include" the class library project into your API's Visual Studio Solution. I updated my answer.

Comment: @GuillaumeS. I understand both those options, and appreciate the input. Making a nuget package might have to be my solution for now, but I would still like to understand the process of using a `.NETStandard` dll as a reference in a `.NETCoreApp`, and why this isn't working for me.

This particular library is going to be used across many applications. so the second option doesn't seem as lucrative.

Comment: @Steve'Kepano'Eggering [Read my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42428772/7135977) (not my comments). There is a link to the Microsoft documentation that can help you to understand.